# UIRefreshControl wrong size on UITableView/UICollectionView

Tags: ios, uitableview, uicollectionview

I'm trying to use a `UIRefreshControl` that has a colored background. I found that the `UIRefreshControl`'s size is actually inaccurate when you use it on a `UITableView` or `UICollectionView`.

To highlight this, I set a background color to the `UIRefreshControl` and to the cells.

How do I fix this gap? This is driving me nuts. It looks very unprofessional and seems to be hidden with people using white `UIRefreshControl`s.

Here the `UIRefreshControl` is flush against the `UITableView`
[image: Resting position]

Now we start to see a little bit of a gap

[image]

Now the gap is much bigger

[image]

To reproduce this, simply have a plain Storyboard with a UITableViewController.

Relevant code:

```
  self.refreshControl = [[UIRefreshControl alloc] init];
  [self.refreshControl setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
  self.refreshControl.tintColor = [UIColor clearColor];
```

Repo with code: 
https://github.com/Lyricalpanda/RefreshControl/tree/master/RefreshControl

Comment: "To reproduce this, simply have a plain Storyboard with a UITableViewController." This does not happen with me. You seem to have set the inset for the tableview or something.

Comment: Unrelated - based on the black bars you seem to be missing either the launch screen storyboard or the appropriate launch images.

Comment: @beyowulf Haven't set any insets in code and verified none were set in IB somehow. Plus insets would make it so that there would always be a gap, not while scrolling. Here's a github of a project that it's happening to me on iPhone 6 simulator (9.0). Running XCode 7.0. Verified this happens on a device too.  https://github.com/Lyricalpanda/RefreshControl/tree/master/RefreshControl

Comment: @rmaddy Thanks! The images were based on an outdated custom `UIRefreshControl` tutorial project I dabbled in. Good catch though, was wondering why it was doing that.

Comment: @LyricalPanda I take it that fixed it?

Comment: @beyowulf Unfortunately not. That only fixes the black top and bottom parts. It seems that the white line while scrolling happens out of the box on iOS.

Answer (score 1):

Well, in your sample app, I can make that white gap go away by saying:

```
self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
```

But if that's acceptable you don't need to set the refresh control's background color at all just the view's.

Comment: Thanks for taking a crack at it! Unfortunately we're trying to have the `[tableView background]` property be `clearColor` so that there can be a visible gap between the `cells`. By making the `view Background` the same as the `UIRefreshControl`, this becomes much more complicated :(